# Completion of a torsion-free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, $K$ its field of fractions, $P$ a non-zero prime ideal of $R$. Let $\hat R_P$ be the *completion* of $R$ w.r.t the valuation $v_P$ induced by $P$ and let $L$ be a torsion-free $R$-module.

> Is it true that the completion $\hat R_P\otimes_R L$ of $L$ is a torsion-free $\hat R_P$-module?

I'm not sure how to even approach this question. Would the fact that $R$ is dense in $\hat R_P$ w.r.t $v_P$ be helpful?

Many thanks!

Comment: I guess the two rings used for the scalar extension of $L$ are completely different. Originally I thought that the theme of proving that the torsion free module $L$ stayed torsion free under extension of scalars was the same for the two questions. Regards

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that any torsion element is in the valuation ideal, $PR_P$ which we will just call $P$ by abuse of notation. If not, then we can find an inverse for the torsion number, $n$, in $R_P - P=R_P^\times$, and this would imply $1\cdot v=0$ for some $v\in R_P\otimes_R L$, which implies $v$ was $0$ to begin with.

But then it must be that we need only check if there is $\pi^k$ torsion for some $k$, and $\pi$ a generator for $P$.

But then $\pi^k\in R$ already, so we would have detected it from the start.

Comment: What about the field $\mathbb F_p:=\mathbb{Z}/{p\mathbb{Z}}$ as a module over itself? It has characteristic $p$ and is torsion free over itself. Regards

Comment: @user149343 :  You're right, this proof works fine without the characteristic assumption. Also:  $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a bad example since treating a finite field as a locally compact field always gives the discrete topology, so completion is always trivial.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if $x\cdot v=0$ where $x\in R_P$ and $v\in R_P\otimes_R L$ with $v\neq0$ then $x$ is of the form $\pi^ku$ where $k\in \mathbb N$ and $u\in R_P^\times$, and so $\pi^kv=0$. We can choose $\pi\in R$ so $\pi^k\in R$. But how does this help us- $v$ is in $R_P$ not $R$? Sorry if I'm missing something easy. Regards

Comment: @user149343 $v\in L$ not $R$, remember we're acting on the module with the ring, the module itself is not a part of the ring.

Comment: I'm not sure why if all pure tensors are non-torsion then the same is true for arbitrary tensors. Also why does $1_R\otimes_R rr'v=0 \implies rr'v=0_L$? For this don't we need to assume that $L$ is $R$-free? Regards

Comment: @user149343 I revised my comment almost immediately, again to avoid the complex problems involved with such things. really you just need $v\in L$, you were thinking it was in $R$ or such, that's not how things work.

The answer to the latter problem is simple though:  the module AXIOMS say that if you have an $R$-module, $M$, $1\cdot v=v$ for every $v\in M$.

Comment: You are right, I should have written $v\in L_P$ not $R_P$.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Let's assume that the pure tensor $1_R\otimes_R r'rl \in R_P\otimes_R L$ is zero. How does your last comment help us in deducing that $r'rl=0$? Regards